# How do I only show the last N lines of output in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I want to train a neural network, and I want to go at it for tens of thousands of generations. This generates a lot of output, and I only want to see, say, last N lines of it. One solution is to call `clear_output` from `IPython.display` every N iterations, but I don't like it, because it clears all of the output, not leaving me with anything.

Is there anything better that I can do?